# Сравнение производительности штатных компиляторов Delphi, pascalABC.net и C++

Tags: c++, delphi, строки, производительность, pascalabc.net

В очередной раз очередной студент с горящими глазами объявил, что "всё, что у нас написано на Delphi - медленно и безобразно и, если мы уж не хотим перейти на C++, то почему бы не перейти на pascalABC.net, он быстрее значительно".

Студенту поручили проверить всё это. Конкретная задача (постараюсь определить в терминах скорости компиляторов, как мне указали в комментариях): сравнить производительность штатных компиляторов Delphi, PascalABC.net и MS VS (версий, которые у нас имеются. Не такие древние, хотя по академической лицензии иметь всегда последнее порой сложно). Выкладки, которые он привёл из сети, в целом не особо убедительны. Да, быстрее, но в конкретных примерах. Как они относятся к нашим задачам - не совсем ясно. Студенту поручили, в итоге, всё проверить на практике.

Вопрос, может, кто-то уже сталкивался с необходимостью сравнения скорости на больших биоинформатических проектах (или похожих: основной массив работы - строки, большое их количество, сравнение, точный и нечеткий поиск, построение деревьев, циклы, статистика) Delphi vs PascalABC.net и, возможно, C++?

Принцип подхода к снаряду понятен, объём работы - тоже. Но, мне, как куратору студента, хотелось бы понимать, насколько правильно он выполнил свою работу. Для этого неплохо было бы и сравнить его результаты с уже имеющимися, если таковые есть.

Comment: Есть ведь разные компиляторы для `delphi`...

Comment: Нет такого понятия как производительность языка. Зато есть компилятор, качество его кодогенерации и набор применяемых им оптимизаций. Даже код на том же C++ может безбожно тормозить на штатном компиляторе MSVC 6 и летать под наисвежайшим GCC.

Comment: сравнение глупое и бессмысленное. Лучше писать  на том, что лучше знаете.  На ютубе смотрел видео, где человек рассказывает, как он сделал большой кластер на хадупе, который долго-долго считал по его данным. А потом один из зрителей небольшим скриптом на ноуте посчитал за несколько минут...

Comment: @KoVadim "Один из зрителей" решил задачу, которую решали численно, математически, - бывает, и нередко. Многие бы биоинформатики желали бы так решать свои задачи, но увы - невозможно.

Comment: [Это](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/c.html) не ответ на конкретно ваш вопрос, но достаточно интересные измерения производительности множества программ, решающих одни и те же задачи на разных языках. Полазайте, поглядите (в т.ч. там есть сорсы)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Похоже, такие желания появляются у каждого третьего студента :) По крайней мере, у нас часто возникают схожие студенческие задачи, особенно, если приходят студенты с мехмата или ВИТ и желают заниматься только программированием. Ну, ладно, это лирика.*

По делу. Сейчас у нас силами трёх студентов решается большая задача по оптимизации конвейера `анализ->расшифровка->расчеты->моделирование->диагноз`, в ней, в частности, большую часть занимают проблемы производительности наших пакетов, в том числе, созданных разными компиляторами. В списке компиляторов есть все три указанных вами, так что я могу в целом описать картину сравнения. Могу дать промежуточные выводы. Подробные данные могу опубликовать только с разрешения авторов (дипломная работа не окончена), если оно будет, я дополню ответ.

Сразу приведу класс задач в наших пакетах. Это работа с огромными и маленькими строками, матрицами (в меньшей степени), проблемы поиска, динамическое программирование, множества, ряды Фурье и вейвлеты, ввод-вывод. Время расчёта результата анализа одного пациента при работе в один поток может достигать 10-12 часов, так что погрешностями в долях секунды при замере времени работы можно пренебречь. В расчет принималось среднее от отношения времен работы. Для разных ситуаций количество замеров разное, но всегда больше 7.

Версии компиляторов: Delphi for Win64 31.0 (Delphi 10.1), PascalABC.net 3.2.0.1415, VS 2015 (14.00.24720)

1. Пакет на Delphi, написанный с использованием только стандартных методов и функций Delphi, в один поток, уступал по производительности и PascalABC.net и, тем более, C++. Разница в нашем основном пакете могла достигать, в зависимости от данных, 1.3 раза с паскалем и до 1.5х раз с C++ (есть разные результаты для разных процессоров, это самая большая разница). Так что, если не желаете заниматься профилировкой, а скорость работы критична, я бы не рекомендовал писать на Delphi.
2. То же самое, но в многопоточном виде. Большинство наших задач успешно распараллеливаются, так что мы охотно применяем многопоточность. Разница Delphi супротив C++ в худшем случае осталась около 1.5х раз, с PascalABC.net - 1.1 раза. Скорее всего, в PascalABC.net многопоточность ещё плохо "вылизана".
3. Многопоточная профилированная задача. В данном случае были выявлены "бутылочные горла" и проблемные места переписаны на ассемблере. Это было сделано для Delphi и C++. PascalABC.net не поддерживает встроенный ассемблер, были сделаны попытки подключения библиотек, но ожидаемого успеха пока не добились. Как итог, сравнение Delphi с C++ - отставание в 1.15 раза (на Intel), неоптимизированный пакет PascalABC.net проиграл Delphi в 1.6 раза
4. То же самое, но с поддержкой SIMD. Вот тут уже почти паритет. Отставание Delphi от C++ на процессорах Intel - 1.06 раза (было бы интересно скомпилировать компилятором от Intel с интринсиками, но не знаю, будет ли реализовано или нет), на процессорах AMD - 1.01 раза. PascalABC не сравнивался - причина в п. 3

Была еще проведена оптимизация под конкретные ядра. Тут вообще интересные результаты (в частности, при оптимизации под ядра Zen на Ryzen 1700 в 16-типоточном приложении пакет на Delphi был повторяемо быстрее всех, что мы пока не можем внятно объяснить), но в промежуточном выводе они не представлены, без разрешения авторов я их дать не могу.

Comment: "Пакет на Delphi, написанный "по умолчанию", без профилировки, в один поток" - вот это подозрительная ремарка. Кто-нибудь рецензировал код, на предмет явных ошибок? Идентичность кодов проверялась? (дебаг вместо релизной сборки, те же передачи структур по ссылкам, а не по значениям, и т.п.)

Comment: Разумеется, проверялась, поскольку работа важная, и я далеко не единственный куратор. Поскольку для Delphi такой версии программы изначально не существовало (пакет создавался изначально в один поток, но сразу с большинством оптимизаций, применяемых на сегодняшний день), она была получена из однопоточной версии заменой всех ассемблерных оптимизаций на стандартные функции Delphi. Результаты всех программ всегда сверяются. Также контроль осуществляется в сверке Debug/Release при вызове функции и при возврате значений. Ошибки возможны, но пока явных не обнаружено.

Comment: Пакет по умолчанию - жаргонизм, принятый нами, чтобы обозначить точку отсчета. Здесь неуместен, согласен, поправил.

Comment: А Delphi 10.1 - это все таки отдельный компилятор, а не надстройка над LLVM? У меня как-то сложилось впечатление что нативных компиляторов для Delphi после 7 версии не выпускали.

Comment: @VTT Сейчас поправлю ответ, он брался из краткого отчёта, поэтому указана версия IDE вместо версии компилятора. Но, вообще, это именно компилятор. Embarcadero Delphi for Win64 compiler version 31.0

Comment: "она была получена из однопоточной версии заменой всех ассемблерных оптимизаций на стандартные функции Delphi." к сожалению, в отличие от c++, много стандартных функций делфи - жуткие тормоза (в сравнении), потому что оптимизацией эмба не заморачивается от слова совсем.

Answer (score 3):

Выберите характерные тестовые задачи и опишите их алгоритмы, выделите типовые показатели производительности (ТПП) алгоритмов. 
Закодируйте алгоритмы на всех интересующих языках, в том числе обеспечьте вычисление ТПП. 
При необходимости для программы на одном языке используйте различные компиляторы, аппаратные платформы. 
Прогоните то что получилось и сравните результаты. 
В каком ВУЗе вы учитесь? Почему интуитивно то что я написал не удается понять?

Comment: `для программы на одном языке используйте различные компиляторы` — думаю, это стоит поместить в начало ответа. Остальное уже не так принципиально.

Comment: Я давно уже не студент :)  Более того, не программист, а медик, умеющий программировать. И, как руководитель отделения, тесно связанного с биоинформатикой, обязан курировать студентов, которым задания даёт их кафедра :)

Comment: @Arhad использовать различные компиляторы? Между разными версиям компилятора Delphi мы уже сравнивали - результаты отличаются в пределах погрешности. Скачок был при переходе, ЕМНИП, XE6 -> XE7, но небольшой.

Comment: у любого компилятора есть своя ахиллесова пята - всё зависит от решаемых задач. Часто компилятор и язык вообще ни при чем, например когда применяются какие-то специализированные библиотеки, например для обработки изображений.

Answer (score 2):

- Насчёт производительности в расчётах. Пишу на Delphi **научные
  программы** (выч.гидродинамика) уже лет 15. До этого были Fortran,
  PL\1. Знаю, что сейчас считается хорошим тоном плюнуть в сторону
  Delphi, и похвалить Java или C#. Пробовал и их, разумеется. Однако ж,
  остался на Delphi: мне он удобнее в первую очередь при разработке
  GUI, и во-вторых - при общении с различными БД, в которых хранятся
  исходные данные для научных расчётов.

  - Далее. Для научного софта ключевым моментом является быстродействие и многопоточные вычисления. По быстродействию - пусть
    тот *"студент с горящими глазами"* не слушает никого: пробует сам,
    например, простое обращение матрицы напишет на VS C++, Delphi 64bit,
    Java, C#, Python. Сравнит время выполнения (в цикле - несколько
    обращений матриц, затем в многопоточном режиме вычислений). А только
    потом делает выводы: они его удивят.
  - Последнее время построил доступ из Delphi-кода (интерфейсная часть) к графическому (потоковому) ускорителю (GPU): язык **OpenCL**
    1.2. Для этого языка сам код KERNEL, работающий на видео-карте, пишется на C99 (посл. версии OpenCL 2.0-2.2 - уже С++); компилятор не
    требуется - компилирует сам драйвер видеокарты. Весь код Delphi/C99
    отлично редактируется-анализируется в Embarcadero RAD Studio. Прирост
    в скорости выполнения программ после переноса расчётов на GPU -
    колоссальный, даже в сравнении с многопоточными вычислениями на CPU
    (раз в 30).
  - Мораль. Не агитирую именно за Delphi: на него необоснованно столько сейчас грязи льют (и хоронят уже лет 20), что работу чисто
    под него упомянутый в топике студент вряд ли найдёт. Но вот научиться
    программировать расчёты (или, скажем, обработку изображений) на GPU с
    применением OpenCL (AMD + NVidia + Intel) или CUDA (только NVidia) -
    весьма перспективно. А перескакивать с одного языка на другой
    новомодный - бесполезная трата времени.
    Примеры связки Delphi 64bit OpenCL найдёте поиском в ИНЕТ по этим кл.словам.

Comment: Пожалуйста, попробуйте разбить текст на абзацы, чтобы было легче его прочесть.