# Скорость вычислений в С++ по сравнению с другими приложениями

Tags: c++

Действительно с помощью С++ можно значительно ускорить расчеты больших объемов (большие массивы данных и много раз нужно повторить расчет по времени)?
Ускорить мне нужно по сравнению с Матлабом.

Comment: Да действительно да (Конкретно в сравнении с матлабом).

Comment: Если вы сможете реализовать те же расчёты более оптимальными алгоритмами, чем реализованы в матлабе, то да. А для этого нужно весьма неплохо владеть С++. "Да, действительно, можно" лишь теоретически.

Comment: Смотря с чем сравнивать. В чистой математике можно проиграть фортрану. В оптимизации под ядра Zen мы проиграли Delphi :) Но, в целом, если не прилагать усилий, C++ быстрее. См: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762873/

Comment: @ViktorTomilov: бывает, что если не прилагать усилий, то [C++ медленнее чистого Питона.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9371238/4279)

Comment: Код в Matlab векторизирован, но код на С++ под конкретную задачу всегда будет быстрее, если он правильный, т.е.выполняется за минимальное количество шагов, и максимально эффективно использует ресурсы компьютера в соответствии с задачей. Например, если вы профессионал и знаете, как работает процессор, под конкретную задачу на C++ можно написать код, который не будет уходить за пределы **L2** или вообще **L1** и тогда вы выжмите из процессора максимум производительности. Ведь скорость работы может зависеть не только от скорости выполнения вычислений, но и от скорости работы подсистемы памяти.

Comment: Главное - это правильный ответ, а эффективность дело второе, другой вопрос здесь в том, что сколько времени вы потратите на поиск алгоритма, анализ, написание максимально эффективного кода? Возможно это разница будет намного больше, чем время выполнения на уже готовых решениях, если операция разовая. Вы должны разбираться в архитектуре компьютера и понимать процессы оптимизации, как на уровне машинного кода, так и на уровне алгоритмов и на уровне компилятора C++, иначе быстрее не будет. Matlab тоже не прост, в нем производительность также зависит от написания кода.

Comment: Спасибо всем ответившим,

Comment: Спасибо всем ответившим, чувствую что моя прога в С++ быстрее не будет. Хотя выясню опытным путем.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Да, действительно, можно. Хотя для этого стоит потрудиться (возможно, придется подключать сторонние библиотеки).

Comment: Лучше не отвечать на такие вопросы.

Comment: Точнее, скорее можно ускорить если не использовать библиотеки (вполне вероятно, что эффективные библиотеки как раз уже использует Matlab)

Comment: Оптимистично: получается лучше чем сейчас не будет (чем на матлабе).